# kubernetes error: the server doesn't have a resource type "jenkins"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, gitea

I recently installed **Jenkins** on my **kubernetes cluster** and the `Pod` is always pending when I try the command:

```
kubectl describe "pod name"
```

I get the error: `the server doesn't have a resource type "jenkins"`

I got the same problem when installing **gitea**.

note : I am running **kubernetes** on a virtual machine (local)

Comment: Welcome! That error means that you're not specifying the resource type. It should be

kubectl describe pod jenkinspodname

Comment: @Ruairios, could you post your explanation as an answer ?

Comment: @mario - done, thanks

Comment: @Ruairios i dn't believe the command is the problem .. the issue is that the pod is always pending.

Comment: A pod stuck in pending state can still get described. So that error is independent of whether the pod is pending or not. The error you posted specifically means that it was looking for a resource type (eg pod, deployment, replicaset etc) that isn't there. That might mean it's not in your current namespace. Your error shows that the command you entered is looking for a resource type called 'jenkins', not a pod called 'Jenkins'.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you are not specifying the resource type in your command. So if I have a pod "mypod-zzxch" running in a namespace "services", then the command would be:

```
kubectl describe pod mypod-zzxch -n services
```